# Why does use libc stop cargo from linking my program correctly?

Tags: c, rust, ffi, rust-cargo

I have some C code which I compiled to a `.so` file which i want to be called from a Rust program.

```c
// hello.c

void greet() {
    printf("Hello, world");
}
```

so I compiled it to a shared object file and added it to my build.rs and it worked fine

```rust
// main.rs

#[link(name = "hello")]
extern "C" {
    fn greet();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        greet();
    }
}
```

The problem is the I have a second function in my C code which accepts a `char*` as a parameter so I tried to use `libc::c_char` to communicate between C and Rust but whenever my program doesn't compile when I import `libc`.

```rust
// main.rs

#[link(name = "hello")]
use libc::c_char;
extern "C" {
    greet();
}
```

And I already tried to compile just with import `libc` (because I thought that might have been the problem) but it works perfectly so it seems like the program only doesn't compile when I am using my C shared object and importing the `libc` crate.

This is the error message

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
= note: "cc" 

  = note: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
            "_greet", referenced from:
                project::main::h501a37fa09c5db9f in project.2q2eogqn7p5k3u7s.rcgu.o
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Could you add the code for the other c function and the rust code that uses it? Might be easier to see what is going on

Comment: Its at the top in hello.c

Comment: Are you talking about `printf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#[link]` attribute must be just before the `extern` block. By inserting a `use` between the `#[link]` attribute and the `extern` block, the `#[link]` attribute becomes attached to the `use` and has no effect. (There really should be a warning for this...)

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me, are you sure you compiled a static library that Rust linker can use regardless of what else gets linked into the final executable?

I can only guess that this is whats wrong as you haven't provided how exactly you setup your project, and I'd recommend letting `cc` crate handle it for you, and if you really need something it doesn't have, contribute to it, instead of manually compiling C code and trying to link it in.

---

Example

`build.rs`

```
fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("src/hello.c")
        .compile("hello");
}
```

`src/hello.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void greet() {
    printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

`src/main.rs`

```
use libc::c_char;

#[link(name = "hello")]
extern "C" {
    fn greet();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        greet();
    }
}
```

`cli`

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling link v0.1.0 (~/Desktop/link)
warning: unused import: `libc::c_char`
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use libc::c_char;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.50s
     Running `~/.cargo/target/debug/link`
Hello, world
```